# Javascript addeventlistener hitting click multiple times

Tags: javascript

The below mentioned code will change icon from watched(-) to unwatched(+) and vice-versa in a list of data(list of icon):-

ts code:-

```
const watchListComponent = document.querySelectorAll('.addtoWatchlist');
        if (watchListComponent.length) {
            watchListComponent.forEach((watchItem) => {
                watchItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    console.log('here');
                    watchItem.querySelector('.icon').classList.toggle('iconWatched');
                    watchItem.querySelector('.icon').classList.toggle('iconWatchList');
                });
            });
        }
```

HTML code :-

```
<div class="px-2">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tableInvisibleOption addtoWatchlist tooltipTRWL">
                            <i class="icon icon20 iconWatchList iconShow" (click)="addToWatchList(fundData)"></i>
                            <span class="tooltiptextTRWL">Add to Watchlist</span></a>
                        </div>
```

In the above case, first time if I click on the unwatched(+) icon it is getting changed to watched(-) for ex:- (+) to (-), and the next time if I click it should change from (-) to (+) but the icon is not changing. If I click twice the icon is getting changed from(-) to (+) then if I click twice changing from (+) to (-).

Need to change the icon from (+) to (-) and (-) to (+) on single click.

Comment: Please include a snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) that *demonstrates the issue*.  Your code in isolation is not enough.  Your code *as presented* with implied classes/elements, works fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/n5Lujv84/

Comment: I think there is some missing context. Can you add the HTML to your example?

Comment: @StefanoNepa I have added html code.

Comment: What's `(click)="addToWatchList(fundData)"` do?  What if you remove this and *stick to a single click handler pattern*?

Comment: @freedomn-m on-click, the icon is getting changed and "fundData" has "ID" which will add the selected record to the table.

Basically, I should add the clicked record from a set of records and change the icon of the selected record from (+) to (-). 
Adding a record to a table is done.

Answer (score 0):

Use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). A [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for you

```js
document.addEventListener("click", toggleAddIcon);

function toggleAddIcon(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.classList.contains("icon")) {
    origin.classList.toggle('iconWatchList');
  }
}
```

```css
.icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon.iconWatchList:after {
  content: ' (on list)';
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">click</div>
<div class="icon">click</div>
<div class="icon">click</div>
```

Comment: @Kooilnc I have added the Html in a question, can you kindly check it?

Comment: document.AddEventtListener("click", toggleAddIcon);
I cannot use this because I have other click events in the form with different icons, if I click, other icons are getting affected.